# Dynamic data doesn't update when changing v-model input value in Vuejs

Tags: api, vue.js, data-binding, vuejs2, v-model

I'm trying to add the parameter "pokemonName" to the api url that's being fetched with axios. My goal is to display the JSON data for each new pokemon the that the user enters within an input text field.

Here is my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Pokemon Search</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="app" class="container">

    <div>{{ results }}</div><br />

    Search: <input type="text" v-model.lazy="pokemonName" @change="getPokemon">
  </div>



  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is my js:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      results: [],
      pokemonName: ""
    }
    this.$set(this.pokemonName)
  },
  methods: {
    getPokemon() {
      // await axios
      fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + this.pokemonName)
        //.then(response => (this.results = response.data));
        .then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
          this.pokemonName = data;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(ERROR);
        })
    }
  },
  mounted: function mounted() {
    this.getPokemon()
  }
});
```

Comment: where exactly are you displaying your results? It seems like all you have is a search.

Comment: My bad, just added that in now.

Comment: Are you receiving the data? do you see in your data property? Have you tried to console it?

Comment: I'm only getting {{ results }} and my text input shows [object Object]. (I'm sorry for being a noob, this is one of my first projects with Vue.js)

Comment: try writing inside your function `console.log(data)` and tell us what it says

Comment: It pulls up an array of 20 items (20 pokemon). The url it thinks I'm trying to pull from is https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?offset=20&limit=20, when I'm actually trying to use https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/ + this.pokemonName

Comment: what does the console say inside the function (before the call) for `console.log(this.pokemonName)`?

Comment: Before the call, it still shows the same 20 item array as before. After the call, it seems to show the correct data for the matching pokemonName.

I typed in "ditto" within the text input field and was able to get the correct object for the pokemon named "ditto" within the console. That's a good sign, but now how can we display it to the <div> ? (Thank you so much btw, this has already helped immensely)

Comment: you need to set your `results` to the object, you need to understand what it looks like otherwise you will end up displaying something that looks like this:
"{"data": "somProp: 1234, "prop2": "someString"}} etc.

Comment: Got it to load the correct name to an <h1>. Thanks, man!

Answer (score 0):

Your code working correctly. Type a number to see the name. You need to set the results.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      results: [],
      pokemonName: ""
    }
    this.$set(this.pokemonName)
  },
  methods: {
    getPokemon() {
      // await axios
      fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/' + this.pokemonName)
        //.then(response => (this.results = response.data));
        .then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
          this.results = data.name;
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(ERROR);
        })
    }
  },
  mounted: function mounted() {
    this.getPokemon()
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Pokemon Search</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="app" class="container">

    <div>{{ results }}</div><br /> Search: <input type="text" v-model.lazy="pokemonName" @change="getPokemon">
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```